# Spring Cloud Data Flow pass data to task

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

How can I pass data to my Spring Cloud DataFlow Task?

I need to pass some POJO on which my Task will be operate. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the properties when launching the task. If you want to pass a POJO then make sure your task understand that POJO as properties when passed as arguments.

For passing the properties, you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_launching_a_task)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I've seen that reference, but could you provide please an example of how can I pass props as POJO and how my task can understand them?
I'm using `DataFlowTemplate` for launching task, and all that I see everywhere, when passing them - is that properties are just strings.
For example, here is the `launch` method signature in `TaskOperations`:

`long launch(String name, Map<String, String> properties, List<String> arguments);`

And now I can't figure out how to pass POJO, using properties:(

Comment: You can't pass a POJO for either of those for a simple reason.  You can't pass a POJO as a command line arg or an environment variable.  We don't do any form of serialization before configuring these two and both are fundamentally Strings.

Comment: How can we pass the Task Argument programmatically to Spring Batch Step?